# php variable parsing in double quoted strings

Tags: php, string

while reading about variable parsing in double quoted strings in the php manual I came across 2 examples which are confusing to me. An example of how this works with some code would help greatly. Here is the code from the manual:

```
echo "This works too: {$obj->values[3]->name}";

echo "This is the value of the var named $name: {${$name}}";

echo "This is the value of the var named by the return value of getName(): {${getName()}}";
```

What exactly do these mean? I know that `$obj` is an object. I just don't know what would've been the precursor code of these examples. Any help would be useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: @Dagon I think this question just needs to be renamed... Seems like the content is more about how to interpret variables inside curly brackets (which are inside double quotes), etc.

Comment: @jerdiggity curly braces are explained in the linked duplicate

Comment: @bboy then search on the basics of php OO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use the 3 examples from the manual you gave.

We can provide these variables a name and look at the output to see what they do.

```
$obj->values[3]->name = "Object Value";
$name = "variable";
$variable = "Variable Value"; // You'll see why we need to define this in a minute
$function = "Function Value";
function getName() {
    return "function";
}
```

I imagine you're already seeing where this is going but let's see what this mean for the statements you posted:

```
echo "This works too: {$obj->values[3]->name}"; // This works too: Object Value

echo "This is the value of the var named $name: {${$name}}"; // This is the value of the var named $name: Variable Value

echo "This is the value of the var named by the return value of getName(): {${getName()}}"; // This is the value of the var named by the return value of getName(): Function Value
```

In the first case, it replaces the object value with "Object Value."

In the second `$name` gets interpreted as "variable", which means `{${$name}}` gets interpreted as the value of `$variable`, which is "Variable Value."

The same principle applies to the return value of the function.

Comment: Just read this in the manual which after some thought made things better: `Note:
Functions, method calls, static class variables, and class constants inside {$} work since PHP 5. However, the value accessed will be interpreted as the name of a variable in the scope in which the string is defined. Using single curly braces ({}) will not work for accessing the return values of functions or methods or the values of class constants or static class variables.`

Answer (score 0):

Here follows the examples you posted,

When you use `{}`you make sure the entire path of the object gets evaluated. If you remove them it will only evaluate `$obj->values` which returns `Array`.

```
$obj->values[3] = "Name";
echo "This works too: {$obj->values[3]}"."\n"; // CORRECT: This works too: Name
echo "This works too: $obj->values[3]"."\n\n"; // ERROR:   This works too: Array[3]
```

In the first two examples `$name` is evaluated first, and you will be left with {$mike}. Since you have the curly braces outside the new variable name, this too will be evaluated, and will translate to the string `Michael` instead. In the last example you will be left with `$mike`.

```
$name = "mike"; 
$mike = "Michael"; 
echo "This is the value of the var named $name: {${$name}}"."\n"; // This is the value of the var named mike: Michael
echo "This is the value of the var named $name: {$$name}"."\n";   // This is the value of the var named mike: Michael
echo "This is the value of the var named $name: $$name"."\n\n";   // This is the value of the var named mike: $mike
```

This example is similar to the one above, but instead of using the variable $name, a function is used instead. If you do not have the curly braces `{}` around the function (example #2), but around `$getName()`, PHP will try to to access the `function $getName`, which is not a legal function name. 
The last example $getName() will fetch the value of the variable $getName and the () will be left alone. So if you would have `$getName = "Heya";`, it would become `Heya()`.

```
function getName() { return "mike"; }
echo "This is the value of the var named by the return value of getName(): {${getName()}}"; // This is the value of the var named by the return value of getName(): Michael
echo "This is the value of the var named by the return value of getName(): {$getName()}";  // Fatal error: Function name must be a string
echo "This is the value of the var named by the return value of getName(): $getName()";     // This is the value of the var named by the return value of getName(): ()
```